# "Continue Interacting?" Prompt

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel, office-web-apps

We are hosting excel files in sharepoint (with an Office Web Apps server)

The users get the below message if they don't interact with the excel file after a few minutes. Is there a way to increase this time?

[image: Prompt]

Comment: are you using the excel services? is this for sharepoint online or on prem?

Comment: this is for sharepoint on premise. I believe it is excel services.